# Does Agora.io react native api support ringtone for video calls

Tags: react-native, agora.io, videocall

I would like to initiate a call with the react-native api and play a ringtone on the receiving phone. Is this supported on the api?

Comment: did you ever get anything working with this?

Comment: Yes. Since the API does not support the feature. I had to send a voip notification message to the device and then use CallKit to show the incoming call. Same thing with Android.

Comment: Could you provide some insight into how you did this with an answer below, or perhaps a code sample on github? Would super appreciate your input, would be valuable not only to me but I am sure hundreds of others who wish to integrate this in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From Samyak Jain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60660843/6067894)

> You can check out this library: https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep
>
> It uses callkit on the ios side and connection service on the android side.
>
> We also have some sample apps for IOS and Android that use CallKit and ConnectionService respectively and use Agora RTM. You can find them here: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Advanced-Video/tree/dev/backup/Calling-Interface