# How to show incoming video call using react native agora

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, real-time, agora.io

I want to add real time calling feature in my react native app.
I am using agora with socket.io to make it real time and it's working fine when app is in foreground, but I am stuck when app is closed because socket does not work when app is closed I want to show WhatsApp like incoming call screen. Kindly help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you got any solution for this ?

Comment: No I haven't found anything related to this issue. Only thing I found is that I have to use native android code to achieve this functionality.

Comment: @hamza did you get solution?

Comment: for foreground what i use is real time database  with the help of real time database  if the app is in foreground it will work

Answer (score 2):

You can check out this library: https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep

It uses callkit on the ios side and connection service on the android side.

We also have some sample apps for IOS and Android that use CallKit and ConnectionService respectively and use Agora RTM. You can find them here: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Advanced-Video/tree/dev/backup/Calling-Interface

Comment: Hi Samyak,

How about RN? do you have sample agora RN with callkit and connection service?

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have a sample app for that yet.